# vuepress vue tip and folder structure

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vuepress

I want to show folder structure in my vuepress docs like this one
https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html#default-page-routing

From the github code here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vuejs/vuepress/master/packages/docs/docs/guide/directory-structure.md, I tried the same in my md file

```
::: vue
.
├── docs
│   ├── .vuepress _(**Optional**)_
│   │   ├── `components` _(**Optional**)_
│   │   ├── `theme` _(**Optional**)_
│   │   │   └── Layout.vue
│   │   ├── `public` _(**Optional**)_
│   │   ├── `styles` _(**Optional**)_
│   │   │   ├── index.styl
│   │   │   └── palette.styl
│   │   ├── `templates` _(**Optional, Danger Zone**)_
│   │   │   ├── dev.html
│   │   │   └── ssr.html
│   │   ├── `config.js` _(**Optional**)_
│   │   └── `enhanceApp.js` _(**Optional**)_
│   │ 
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── guide
│   │   └── README.md
│   └── config.md
│ 
└── package.json
:::
```

but it looks like this
[image]

Comment: You're trying to use [containers](https://vuepress.github.io/reference/default-theme/markdown.html#custom-containers), not a code block, right? Are you using the default theme? Do you have the [container plugin](https://vuepress.github.io/reference/plugin/container.html#container-syntax) installed and enabled?

Comment: Will apply container plugin, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VuePress 1.x you can use a [MarkDown Slot](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown-slot.html#why-do-i-need-markdown-slot) and a Vue component to mimic the [directory structure you referenced](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/directory-structure.html#directory-structure). It gets tricky because the VuePress style theme overwrites some of the css, so you need to get hacky with it in the `mounted()` Vue lifecycle hook. To get this working first create the `Directory.vue` component and second create a *MarkDown Slot* in a `.md` file and consume it with the `<Directory slotKey='slot-name' />` component.

```
docs
└─ src
   ├─ .vueress
   |   ├─ components
   |   |  └─ Directory.vue
   |   |
   |   └─ config.js
   |
   └─ consumer
      └─ README.md
```

1. Directory.vue

```html
<template>
    <div ref="directory" class="directory">
        <Content v-bind:slot-key="slotKey" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        slotKey: String,
        codeColor: {
            type: String,
            default: 'azure'
        },
        codeBackground: {
            type: String,
            default: 'rgb(87, 87, 87)' 
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        // Get the div ref named directory
        const directory = this.$refs.directory

        // Remove all the <br> tags that get added
        directory.innerHTML =  directory.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, '')

        const first = directory.firstChild // <div class="content__vue">
        const second = first.firstChild // <p>
        const codes = second.getElementsByTagName('code') // all the <code> tags

        // Change style here to overwrite the theme
        Array.from(codes).forEach((el) => {
            el.style.color = this.codeColor
            el.style.backgroundColor = this.codeBackground
        })
    }

}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .directory {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
        background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
        color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    }
</style>
```

2. README.md

```markdown
<!-- Here we consume the MarkDown Slot in the Directory Vue component -->
<Directory slotKey="my-dir" />

<!-- Here is the MarkDown Slot -->
::: slot my-dir
.  
└── docs
    └── .vuepress _(**Optional**)_
        ├── `components` _(**Optional**)_
        └── `theme` _(**Optional**)_
:::
```

**Note** that the *MarkDown Slot* needs to be in the same file that it is being consumed in. The Slot will not be rendered unless you consume it with the native VuePress component `Content`.

**By the way** I think you meant to use the `::: v-pre` referenced [VuePress/Escaping](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#escaping)